# Extract only if there is only one matching word from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
fruit_type = ['Apple','Banana','Cherries','Dragonfruit']


for row in df['sentence']:
    sentence['fruit_type'] = df['sentence'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(fruit_type) +")", expand=False)
```

Result of the code above is:

```
df
sentence                    | fruit_type
here is an apple            | apple
here is a banana, an apple  | banana
here is an orange, a banana | orange
```

How do I revise the code so that if there are more than 1 fruit type in `df['sentence']`, `df['fruit_type']` will return a NaN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `extract` you can use `exctractall` combined with `groupby` and `apply`:

First, to get all matches:

```
df['sentence'].str.extractall("(" + "|".join(fruit_type) +")")
```

```
        0
match   
0   0   apple
1   0   banana
    1   apple
2   0   banana
```

Note that there is `pandas.MultiIndex`.

Then, using `.groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list)` you will get:

```
0            [apple]
1    [banana, apple]
2           [banana]
```

And finally, after using `.apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else np.nan)`:

```
0     apple
1       NaN
2    banana
```